# SVN: What value should I give to mandatory comment while committing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have to implement a property in svn such that users must provide comments before committing and I happened to do the same but as per below screenshot it is asking the value and I dont understand what should I provide and in which format.

So please help me.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use that property for that purpose. The `tsvn:` prefix indicates that it's a built-in TortoiseSVN feature and, as such, has a very [concrete usage](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html). What exactly do you want to accomplish and why do you think you need to fill that precise property?

Comment: I want whwenever any user commit any file in svn (in particular stream), then svn restrict the commit if log message or comment is empty. A comment must be there in every commit, so I have read that I can do it via properties or hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "Log Sizes" menu item:

[image: New property]

Then set *Minimum number of chars for a commit message* to 1 or greater (to your liking):

[image: Minimum number of chars for a commit message]

The property you were trying to use belongs to bug tracking integration!

Said that, any approach that's based on raw `tsvn:` properties will only work as long as all the developers use TortoiseSVN to commit their changes. If you need something more rock solid you have to implement a server-side hook.

Comment: Thanks but this is not capturing the id of the developer and not even sending the detailed information of commit via email.

Answer (score 0):

Use property tsvn:logminsize

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-minlogmsgsize.html#Project properties